# Hello guys, I'm trying to subset a datarame based on filtering criterion and want to have multiple dataframes (subset version) as a final outcome

Tags: r, loops, dataframe, subset

Trying to subset a dataframe and store results in different dataframes using for loop.

```
apr_bands <- c(58.7,51.5, 25.4, 24.9, 39.9, 64.9, 59.9, 19.9, 67.9, 69.9,  
9.9, 29.9, 49.9, 34.9, 44.9)
df_apr <- data.frame(matrix(NA, nrow = 212, ncol =4))

for(i in length(apr_bands))

{
df_apr <-int_bal %>% filter(APR == apr_bands[i]) %>% select(date1, week, 
interest, balance) %>% group_by(week) %>% summarise(int = sum(interest), 
bal = sum(balance)) %>% mutate(yield = (int/bal)*13*100)
}
 df_apr
```

Comment: And what is the question?

Comment: don't know how to increment dataframes. At the moment, it just store 2 observation for i =1. Any help?

Comment: I don'd understand the question either. If you could spend more time on a reproducible example e.g. using the `dput` function to supply some inputs and expected outputs, that would help a lot. I find if you don't do this early, your question will disappear from the front pages and the question won't be answered. From guessing, the function [split](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.1/topics/split) maybe what you need. It splits a dataframe in to a list of dataframes based on a criteria

Comment: First define df_apr as a list outside the loop with: `df_apr<-list()`.  Then use `df_apr[[i]]`  inside the  loop to store your results.  Now all of your dataframes are store in a list.